# Ending activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity which occurs when a call is received. However, it only works the first time a call is received. What's the best way to make it work for subsequent calls? Should I do something besides startActivity (i.e. is there something like bringActivityToForeground?) or do I need to end the activity when the call is dropped? How would I end an activity?

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
      context.startActivity(myIntent);

    } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
      // TODO: remove the screen?
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly Resuming the Activity once the call is received?

Comment: How would I do that? I think I probably want to end the activity when the call is answered or dropped instead, but I don't know how to do either.

Comment: You could declare the activity `noHistory` attribute in your androidmanifest.xml to `true`. This will finish the activity when it is no longer needed.